# IIS 6 immediate log flush

Tags: iis, logging, iis-6, windows-server-2003

To troubleshoot an issue with a web service, I need to examine the HTTP log created by **IIS 6** on a **Win2003** box. As I'm sure you are aware there is a log buffer that prevents writing to file every request for the sake of performance.

**Can this HTTP log buffer be manually flushed, or temporarily disabled so each request is written to the log file in real-time?**

I realise that on IIS 7 you can do a `netsh http flush logbuffer`. This does not work for 2003/IIS6.

Additionally, this is a production box so I can't restart it, rendering the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters\DisableLogBuffering` reg key hack (http://www.it-notebook.org/iis/article/flush_log.htm) ineffective.

Comment: possibly more appropriate on http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me...

```
netsh http flush logbuffer
```

In detail here...

http://www.commanigy.com/blog/2013/08/14/immediately-flush-iis-log-for-real-time-tail-to-avoid-60-second-buffer-delay